# Angular 4 params with json stringify

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to stringify some parameter to put it in a http patch request my method is something like this

```
let param = JSON.stringify({
code : this.code,
name : this.name,
fieldName: this.data
});
```

In that case I have a param like this:

> code:3,name:'asdf',fieldName: 'col'

But I want the value of fieldName ond not the word fieldName...
Is there a method to expand or evaluate this parameter name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want value of `code` variable to be used as a key name, then you need to use [computed object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) notation:

```
let param = JSON.stringify({
  [code]: this.code,
  [name]: this.name,
  [fieldName]: this.data
});
```

In the old days we would have to create object separately and assign variable keys in separate step using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
let params = {}
params[code] = this.code
params[name] = this.name
params[fieldName] = this.data

let param = JSON.strigify(params)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another issue, maybe i'll open a new question...How can I prevent json stringify to convert Date? Apr 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 is stringified to: 2017-04-17T22:00:00.000Z

Comment: Date will need to be represented somehow if you stringify it. You can always redefine toJSON method of date object to return whatever you need. `const d = new Date; d.toJSON = () => 'Hello'; ...`.